# Will Foreman run under multithreaded passenger?

Tags: foreman

Is it safe to run Foreman under the "thread" concurrency model in passenger, by setting PassengerConcurrencyModel=thread?

It seems like this should be an easy answer to find, but for some reason I'm having trouble.  I've checked the Foreman site and user mailing list, but I'm not seeing anything that talks about concurrency.

Thanks.

EDIT: I'm running Passenger in Apache.

Comment: Hey, do you mean Foreman as in theforeman.org?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently (Jan 2016) not. Foreman is a Rails application and last month we merged upgrade to Rails 4.1 which is considered to be thread-safe by default. But that's just for the Rails stack, we haven't tested Foreman itself and also we have a bunch of libraries (including some native ones) that might not be thread safe.

If you do test this, please share your results with us: http://theforeman.org/support.html

I also raised this topic in our discussion list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foreman-dev/FG6spa6Gy-I